# Xamarion iOS DatePickerRenderer

Tags: ios, xamarin, renderer

I've writed for my `Xamarin` application a couple of `CustomDatePickerRenderer` for Android and iOS. For Android all works fine, for iOS no. I've when create the `DatePicker` Control an exception for an invalid cast.

Here the code(simplyfied):

```
Xamarin interface

class CustomDatePicker : Xamarin.Forms.DatePicker
{
}
```

**iOS Renderer**

```
class CustomDatePickerRenderer : DatePickerRenderer
{

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<DatePicker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (Control == null)
        {
            return;
        }

    }

}
```

**Exception**

```
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
  at (wrapper castclass) System.Object:__castclass_with_cache (object,intptr,intptr)
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) [0x00000] in <4cf9e9e173a04ea3aa841c775e6a23d7>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Platform.CreateRenderer (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) [0x0001b] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Platform.cs:192 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementPackager.OnChildAdded (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement view) [0x00009] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementPackager.cs:63 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementPackager.Load () [0x0001e] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementPackager.cs:36 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetElement (TElement element) [0x000cc] in <4cf9e9e173a04ea3aa841c775e6a23d7>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) [0x00000] in <4cf9e9e173a04ea3aa841c775e6a23d7>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Platform.CreateRenderer (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) [0x0001b] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Platform.cs:192 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementPackager.OnChildAdded (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement view) [0x00009] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementPackager.cs:63 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementPackager.Load () [0x0001e] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementPackager.cs:36 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetElement (TElement element) [0x000cc] in <4cf9e9e173a04ea3aa841c775e6a23d7>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) [0x00000] in <4cf9e9e173a04ea3aa841c775e6a23d7>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Platform.CreateRenderer (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) [0x0001b] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Platform.cs:192 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementPackager.OnChildAdded (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement view) [0x00009] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementPackager.cs:63 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementPackager.OnChildAdded (System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ElementEventArgs e) [0x0000f] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementPackager.cs:113 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Element.OnChildAdded (Xamarin.Forms.Element child) [0x00029] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Element.cs:354 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.OnChildAdded (Xamarin.Forms.Element child) [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:570 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout`1[T].OnChildAdded (Xamarin.Forms.Element child) [0x00000] in <051840eae40a4636884ee6bc6a0d140a>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.OnInternalAdded (Xamarin.Forms.View view) [0x0001d] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Layout.cs:406 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.InternalChildrenOnCollectionChanged (System.Object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) [0x00089] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Layout.cs:396 
  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>:invoke_void_object_NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs (object,System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs)
  at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[T].OnCollectionChanged (System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) [0x00012] in <c3954baf21fc42d6b4b50ba067398247>:0 
  at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[T].OnCollectionChanged (System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, System.Object item, System.Int32 index) [0x00009] in <c3954baf21fc42d6b4b50ba067398247>:0 
  at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[T].InsertItem (System.Int32 index, T item) [0x00024] in <c3954baf21fc42d6b4b50ba067398247>:0 
  at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[T].Add (T item) [0x00023] in <15e850188d9f425bbeae90f0bbc51e17>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.ObservableWrapper`2[TTrack,TRestrict].Add (TRestrict item) [0x0004b] in <051840eae40a4636884ee6bc6a0d140a>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.RelativeLayout+RelativeElementCollection.Add (Xamarin.Forms.View view, Xamarin.Forms.Constraint xConstraint, Xamarin.Forms.Constraint yConstraint, Xamarin.Forms.Constraint widthConstraint, Xamarin.Forms.Constraint heightConstraint) [0x00012] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\RelativeLayout.cs:313 
  at ArgonApp.InserimentoAutoletturaPage+<selectPage>c__async3.MoveNext () [0x00241] in /Users/alessandro/Desktop/Argon Whitelabel/ArgonApp/ArgonApp/Views/InserimentoAutoletturaPage.xaml.cs:406
```

Have you any idea on this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Have u referred this [link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/23562/change-the-text-color-for-xamarin-forms-datepicker) .Refer to ans by Terrance Wood and Joseph Meyer. Few days I required same. I got it working using this link. Hope it helps!!

Comment: Make sure you have added assembly name in your DatePickerRenderer .



class.

Comment: Thank you @luckyShubhra...I look and hope it works :)

Comment: You are welcome @benjamin. Do let me know if it worked for you .